# windows 10 blocks incoming lan traffic

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, lan

I have a laptop with Windows 10 Pro build 2004, PC with Windows 10 Pro build 2004 and an android phone connected on the same lan. The laptop seems to block incoming lan traffic as I can't ping it from neither PC nor phone. I can ping PC and phone from laptop. All devices have set static ip.

The laptop has sharing turned on. I can't recall any other option that would block incoming lan. I also reset firewall rules to default, but that did not help. I do have OpenVPN installed but it's not running.

When I disable the firewall the laptop can be pinged from PC and phone.

Any input as to why it happens would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows OS is blocking incoming ICMP by default.
If you want to allow incoming ICMP you need to edit the firewall rules:
Open `Run` window by pressing `Win+R` and type `wf.msc` and press `Enter`.
Select `Inbound Rules` and then sort rules by protocol by clicking on `Protocol` tab.
Scroll down to ICMP and you will see two rules that look the same:

```
Core Networking Diagnostics - ICMP Echo Request (ICMPv4-In)
```

Notice the `Remote Address` tab. One role applies to `Local subnet` and the other to `Any` subnet.
Select accordingly to your needs.
Right click on the rule and select `Enable`.