# Allowing ICMP (ping) incoming packets in Windows 11 firewall

Tags: networking, firewall, ping, windows-11

I noticed Windows 11 doesn't let ICMP packets through by default. The network needs to be assigned to a non public network and the appropriate firewall rules have to be activated. I found the following firewall rules (in my case it's IP4 in a private network):

1. `Core Networking Diagnostics - ICMP Echo Request (ICMPv4-In)`
2. `File and Printer Sharing - ICMP Echo Request (ICMPv4-In)`

Activating either of those rules allows ping requests to go through. The description for both rules is the same so why the different names? Does it matter which one I activate?

Comment: Cf. [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1137912/ping-to-windows-10-not-working-if-file-and-printer-sharing-is-turned-off/1627195#1627195) and [these](https://superuser.com/questions/1683853/cannot-ping-a-windows-11-machine/1687643#1687643) [two](https://superuser.com/questions/1170699/cant-ping-a-windows-10-through-ubuntu-both-connected-to-the-same-switch/1627183#1627183) from [mivk](https://superuser.com/users/53547/mivk). [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1599157/windows-10-blocks-incoming-lan-traffic/1599158#1599158) could be the first mentioning *Core Networking Diagnostics*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between the two settings, although not in their effect.

The difference is that disabling File and Printer Sharing in Windows
also disables the firewall rule of
"File and Printer Sharing - ICMP Echo Request (ICMPv4-In)",
so disables PING.

If you want PING to be allowed no matter if File and Printer Sharing is
enabled or not, you should enable
"Core Networking Diagnostics - ICMP Echo Request (ICMPv4-In)".

Comment: Thanks, more specific: this is only for "File and Printer Sharing" settings that are accessed via Control Panel - Advanced sharing settings (the settings within the network adapter settings don't matter!).